# Able to upload file but non retrieve/diplay them - Page not found

Tags: django

I am creating a website in Django and Postgres where a user can answer multiple questions and upload some PDFs.

I am able to upload the PDF but not to display it. I want the user to be able to click on a link, and a new webpage opens containing the PDF.

In my **details.html** I wrote the code:

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{project.thirdquestiondetail.third_seven.url}}">Click here to see the file</a>
```

But, if the user clicks on the links, he gets this messages:

[image: Error]

I have the following:

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('conditions/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='conditions.html'), name='conditions'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**mysite/settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static/')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

As said, I am pretty sure the PDF is uploaded. In fact, if I login as superuser in the admin panel, I can see the PDF.
[image: Admin panel]

**HOWEVER** if I click it, I get the same 404 error reported above

I think the error is in my **settings.py** when I definied my `/media/`. So I checked several similar questions but it seems my settings are in line with the chosen answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that also the upload is not actually working.

I solved as follow:

1) In my **views.py** I have to change the `request.POST['chosen-name']` to `request.FILES['chosen-name']`

2) Add in my hard-coded html form the tag: `enctype="multipart/form-data` in my **template.html**

So from:

```
  <form method="post">..</form>
```

to:

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">..</form>
```

Check: [Django FileField upload is not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983885/django-filefield-upload-is-not-working-for-me)

Answer (score 0):

After making those changes quit and rerun `manage.py runserver`

try changing this `<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{project.thirdquestiondetail.third_seven.url}}">Click here to see the file</a>`

to `<a href="{% get_media_prefix %}{{project.thirdquestiondetail.third_seven.url}}">Click here to see the file</a>`

Comment: I get `Invalid block tag on line 64: 'get_media_prefix', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif`