# django form with image input

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a form to edit an profile picture in django, but is not working because the `if form.is_valid()` is always false and I don´t know why. The only thing I want to know is how to it properly.

My Html is:

```
<form class="form-group row" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="profile_avatar" accept="image/*">
<button type="submit" name="avatarProfile" class="btn btn-brand btn-bold kt-btn-profile">Actualizar foto</button>
</form>
```

My forms.py is:

```
class Perfil(forms.Form):
    picture = forms.ImageField()
```

and my view.py is:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if request.method=='POST':
                form = Perfil(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    picture = form.cleaned_data.get("profile_avatar")
                    user_id = self.request.session.get('user_id')
                    User.objects.filter(user_id = user_id).update(picture_uri = picture)
                    return redirect('core:home')
                else:
                    return redirect('core:home')
            else:
                return redirect('core:home')
        except:
            return redirect('core:home')
```

Comment: You need to pass `request.FILES` to your form: `form = Perfil(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django FileField upload is not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983885/django-filefield-upload-is-not-working-for-me)

Comment: @IainShelvington No, It doesn´t worked

Comment: The `name` of your input is wrong, it should be "picture" not "profile_avatar"?

Comment: @IainShelvington But the form.is_valid()  is always false, so the name is not necesary the error

Comment: can you show your models?