# Problem is that image is not saving . when i am select image and upload all code working properly but image does not save django

Tags: django, django-views, django-media

Problem is that image is not saving. when I am select an image and upload all the code working properly but the image does not save. I checked all the code line by line I do not understand what's the problem. I also see the media file any image is saved or not, but the image wasn't saved.

this is models.py in this file I use the image field
**models.py**

```py
class Answer (models.Model):
  question=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  img=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='Answer_Img')
  detail=RichTextUploadingField()
  add_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


  def __str__(self):
    return self.detail
```

**forms.py**

```py
 class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model=Answer
            fields=('detail','img')
            labels={'img':'Upload Image'}
```

**views.py**

```py
def answer(request,pk,slug):
    try:
        trend=Question.objects.get(pk=pk,slug=slug)
    except:
        raise Http404("Post Does Not Exist")
    tags=trend.tags.split(',')  
    ans=Answer.objects.filter(question=trend)
    answerform=AnswerForm
    if request.method=='POST':
        answerData=AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if answerData.is_valid():
            answer=answerData.save(commit=False)
            answer.question=trend
            answer.user=request.user
            answer.save()
            p=messages.success(request,'Answer has been submitted.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(trend.slug)
    
    return render(request,"ask/answer.html" ,{
        'trends':trend,
        'tags':tags,
        'answer':ans,
        'form':answerform,
        
        })
```

**answer.html**

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="py-5 text-center bg-secondary text-white">
      <h1 class="mb-3">Upload Image</h1>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}} 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Upload">
      </form>
      </div>
      {% else %}
    <h3><P>Sign In/Sign Up before posting answers</P></h3>
    <h4><li><a href="{% url 'account_login' %}" class=" text-left text-info">Sign In</a></li><h4>
    <h4> <li><a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class=" text-left text-info">Sign Up</a></li><h4>

{% endif %}
```

**settings.py**

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
   # my url patterns here
]
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django FileField upload is not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983885/django-filefield-upload-is-not-working-for-me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use request.files to get the img. please check if the media folder is in your base directory and the subfolder is named correctly.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    
    answer_form = Answer_form(data=request.POST)

    if(answer_form.is_valid()):
        ans = answer_form.save(commit=False)
        #ans.user = user

                
        if 'img' in request.FILES:
            ans.img = request.FILES['img']
        
        ans.save()
    
    else:
        print(answer_form.errors)
```

**Here is the documentation page :**

[File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/)